# How to hide AJAX requests (JavaScript code) as Much as We Can?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security

I have a LIKE button `(<a> link)` under each post. When User Clicks on this LIKE button, it sends AJAX requests and do some process. I am tracking the clicking on LIKE button through the following way. 
I have a `ajax.js` file in which I have the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.like").click(function(event) {
        // statements
   });

});
```

But It is very easy to find the javascript code on each node using [**Visual Event**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim) or any other available tool. When I Run this **[Visual Event](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim)** it Highlights all the nodes that have any event listener attached to them and When I Hover my Mouse Cursor to the LIKE Button, It displays all the code which I have written in  `$("a.like").click(function(event) { ..... });`

Althought It is not possible to completely hide the Javascript or AJAX requests, But I want to hide it as much as possible. I have seen so many sites, where are so many links (buttons) that sends AJAX requests but they do not show any event listener attached to them or any code using Visual Event or other tools.

Can I put my Javascript / AJAX code to some where else than `$(document).ready(function()`, Some Where at Higher Level where It is not as visible as now.

Note: For More clarity Please Check [**this site**](http://www.siasat.pk), where you can see the Like Button (link) that do no show any event listener attached to it.

Comment: You can try to hide it all you want, but you won't be able to hide it from the network tab which is the first place anyone who knows about ajax requests will look if they want to know what ajax request is being sent.

Comment: Everyone that has the ability to mess with you WILL mess with you if they want to no matter how hard you try to hide this. In fact, the more you try to hide, the more incentive they have to show you how futile it is to try. My suggestion - just protect the receiving scripts so they only do what you want them to do. Or don't use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could bind all event listeners to the document itself?

```
$(document).on( "click", "a.like", function() {
    //statements
} );
```

It won't really be much more effective at hiding, but maybe it would fool the tools you are worried about.